# How to make okular open http/https links in PDFs with firefox?

Tags: freebsd, firefox, pdf, url, okular

I'm on FreeBSD and have compiled and installed the graphics/okular port (i.e. not much else of KDE4 other than okular's dependencies.) This has installed version 1.8.0. I start my X11 manually with `startx` and use FVWM as the window manager.

When I open a PDF with okular and click a link to, say, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601, a dialog box opens saying

> Select the program you want to use to open the file ISO_8601

I select `/usr/local/bin/firefox`. Then okular downloads the file ISO_8601 to a local directory, `$HOME/.cache/kioexec/krun/13965_0/ISO_8601` and opens that file with firefox. The result is ugly, since all the CSS style is missing.

How can I make okular not download an URL, but pass it straight to firefox?
I'm willing to hack mailcaps, mime-types, or even frob KDE XML files deep down in my directory tree.

The file is available [here](http://www.schweikhardt.net/test.pdf). See page 4, link to ISO. The PDF is created with DocBook and Apache FOP 2.3 as the final conversion step to PDF.

Other readers, such as qpdfview do open the link directly in Firefox.

Comment: Can you share your PDF file?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, I added a link.

Comment: I just tested that within a KDE system Ocular uses KDEinit to handle links. I suppose on configuring Ocular on your system, KDEinit is not found, so instead downloading is selected as the default action for links. Please check whether configure checks for KDEinit. Then the easiest solution could be to install KDEinit prior to building Ocular.

Comment: @Philippos Okular installs kf5-kinit-5.60.0_1 as a dependency, and there is a /usr/local/bin/kdeinit5. It isn't started, since I use plain X11 with fvwm as the window manager. But even after starting kdeinit5, and then okular, it still downloads URLs.